# How to print String buffer lines from last to first order

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I have requirement to print String buffer lines as last to first order.

Example :toString of Stringbuffer method is printing below output:

```
this
is
some
text
```

Desired output:

```
text
some
is
this
```

Comment: StringBuffer is not line-oriented. You'll have to split by newline and then iterate over the resulting string array in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to create an array, iterate over it.

```
String s = new String("this\nis\nsome\ntext");
String []tokens = s.split("\n");
for(int i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
   System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

---

```
 StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("this\nis\nsome\ntext");
    String []tokens = s.toString().split("\n");
    for(int i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
       System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

---

A better memory less approach would be.

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("this\nis\nsome\ntext");
        String word = ""; 
        for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) != '\n')
            {
                word = s.charAt(i) + word;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(word);
                word = "";
            }
        }
        if(!word.equals(""))
            System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer is a final class so you cannot extend it and override its toString() method to achieve what you want to do. You will have to handle it in your code.

you will have to do something like this :

```
public class Reverse {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer s =new StringBuffer();
    s.append("this\nis\nsome\ntext");
    String[] rev = s.toString().split("\n");
    for(int i=rev.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        System.out.println(rev[i]);
    }

}
}
```

o/p :

```
text
some
is
this
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer does not, by itself, have the capacity to return the lines the way you want them. You can either get the whole string from the buffer and use string.split("\n") to split it into an array, which you can then iterate over back to front, or create a class of your own that provides a function that handles such an operation

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do it:

```
    String[] lines = myStringBuffer.toString().split(System.lineSeparator()); //or use any other character for splitting       
    for(int i=lines.length; i>0; i--) {
        System.out.println(lines[i-1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer or String also has a lastIndexOf.

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("this\nis\nsome\ntext");
final String EOL = "\n"; // Or "\r\n" or even "\u0085".
for (int pos = buf.length(); pos > 0; ) {
    int before = buf.lastIndexOf(EOL, pos);
    before = before == -1 ? 0 : before + EOL.length();
    String line = buf.substring(before, pos);
    System.out.println(buf);
    pos = before - EOL.length();
}
```

Note: StringBuilder is better.